# Incrementing a counter within a lambda - Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using Vert.x after working with Node.js for a few years and am trying to replicate some of the functionality we'd see in require('async')

```
package huru.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface AsyncCallback {
  public void cb(Object e, Object v);
}

interface AsyncTask {
  public void run(AsyncCallback cb);
}

interface FinalCallback {
  public void run(Object e, List<Object> v);
}

public class Async {

  static void Parallel (List<AsyncTask> tasks, FinalCallback f) {

    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++){

        tasks.get(i).run((e,v) -> {

          if(e != null){
            f.run(e, null);
            return;
          }

          count++;  // ! here, count needs to be final ??
          results.set(i,v);  

          if(count == tasks.size()){
               f.run(null, results);
          }

        });

    }

  }

}
```

the above is getting there, but I get this error:

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively
>   final

I assume it's a similar problem that we see in JS where the value of i might change as the loop continues.

Anyone know how to mitigate this one? Wrapping it in a self-invoking function would be how to do this with JS.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm it's been awhile since I did some Java, isn't i available in the scope?

Comment: @AlexanderMills - It's as you said in your question: `i` may change, and the lambda isn't allowed to close over a variable that may change. You could declare a variable within the loop body's scope and copy `i` to it, then use that variable (since it won't change).

Comment: (Nice one, BTW, putting the MCVE in the question!)

Comment: Err, make it `final`? Is this such a mystery?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the question, I need to use a counter within the lambda...

Comment: @user207421 you lack imagination, try answering the question given the update, using a counter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how can I petition to reopen the question?

Comment: @AlexanderMills - The updated question is also a duplicate. The solution in that situation is to (again) give the lambda a final (or effectively final) value to close over: An object reference. Then make the counter an instance member of that object. :-) So `Counter c = new Counter();` and `c.incrementValue();` in the lambda and `c.getValue()` when you need the current value. (Sometimes you see people abusing arrays for this: `int[] c = new int[1];` and then `++c[0];`. But...

Comment: Thanks different solution using the object wrapper, but that should work I guess

Comment: It's pretty much how you do it. The variables the lambda uses have to be final (or effectively final). I remember the first time I ran into this situation and found the answer and went "Oh, that's so...obvious...and yet, seems like cheating." :-)

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why primitives have to be final but objects don't but who knows